# How serious are believers in the private language argument?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein, qualia, private-language

From time to time I come across people who endorse Wittgenstein's notion that language is a fundamentally public activity, and that a private language would be meaningless.

I always feel somewhat incredulous at these claims. To me it seems obvious that meaningful things are constantly going on in my mind that others are not aware of, and I have trouble imagining that anyone would really deny this. So I think, even believers in the [private language argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/private-language/) (PLA) must *not* deny it, they must be just saying the public aspects of language are more important or deserve more central focus, or that it's impractical to communicate private experiences. But I'm not sure because I have rarely had this confirmed to me by a believer in the PLA.

So please clarify for me what PLA believers actually think, by confirming or denying the following statements. I'm *guessing* that most PLA believers would affirm most of these.

1. People have private mental lives.
2. People have subjective experiences.
3. Pain is real.
4. People have P-consciousness.
5. People have qualia.
6. A person may go off alone and think by himself.
7. Language is used to transmit concepts from one person's mind to another. That is: there was a private concept in one person's mind, then a public utterance, and then a similar private concept appeared in a second person's mind.
8. A person, alone, may use language to conjure images in his own mind. Assuming he does not have aphantasia. (If you are a PLA believer, do you have aphantasia?)
9. There is an objective reality, independent of what people say about it.
10. A social consensus, even a unanimous one, can be incorrect.
11. People often have an [internal dialogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrapersonal_communication).
12. A person may decide that the word "lurrim" (for example) will be his private synonym for "table," tell this to no one else, and use this word in a meaningful way in his internal dialogue.
13. If a person has a literal, physical, beetle in a box (as Wittgenstein famously discussed as a metaphor), shown to no-one else, then statements the person makes about the literal beetle are still meaningful and may be true or false depending on how well they match the physical characteristics of the beetle.
14. A person may hear what others say, but then he must decide for himself whether he will believe it, based on his own sense of reason. Ultimately, this personal sense of reason is the "gatekeeper" of what beliefs go into a person's mind.
15. Psychology is a legitimate field of study.

Here is a second set of statements, about what I *think* (but please confirm), PLA believers consider unique about their perspective, assuming they do assent to statements 1-15.

16. Language is primarily a social activity.
17. It can be difficult, often impossible, for a person to accurately share his private mental experiences with others.
18. As a practical matter, because of the difficulty of sharing private mental experiences, we should avoid speaking about them in a philosophical context. The potential for confusion and talking past each other is too high.
19. It is better to "think with other people," trying to build consensus and adopting existing consensus, than to ruminate or meditate by oneself.

I'm not looking for lengthy discussion of each of these, just assent/dissent. Right now I'm trying to determine *what* PLA believers believe, not (right now) why they believe it.

As for myself, I assent to 1-17, deny 18 and 19.

Comment: Colloquially, "private language" attaches to private use of public language, "things going on in mind that others are not aware of", which 1-15 are about. 16-19 are beside the point, it is not about importance of public aspects or ease of communication. Wittgenstein was addressing philosophical abuses of the concept in sense data and phenomenological theories, not colloquial or scientific uses. His "private language" is one set up to refer to private events without accessible external correlates, and so no cross-checks on the reference, even in principle. As such, it fails to refer.

Comment: @Conifold Okay. I would have thought #18 to be the crux of the matter - as it is the PLA "watered down" a bit to practical difficulty of communication rather than outright impossibility of communication. Anyway, do you find Wittgenstein's arguments convincing yourself, and if so, which statements do you affirm?

Comment: The point is not difficulty or impossibility, but rather that "private language" is a covert oxymoron, the term is only superficially descriptive. *Whatever* is done will not answer to specifications, but similar sounding meaningful descriptions tend to give us the opposite impression. I find the negative part convincing, that private ostension on its own cannot set up a referring language, but not that public practice is the only circumstance that can. In particular, Azzouni's alternative  in [The Rule-Following Paradox](https://newprairiepress.org/biyclc/vol5/iss1/1/) looks plausible to me.

Comment: @Conifold Alright, I've skimmed it, and correct me if I'm wrong, but Azzouni's core point is that a person alone on an island needs two things to form a language without social interaction. (1) a disposition to recognize when he is mistaken in his use of language to describe his environment (2) a coherent practice to correct himself over time in a way that produces genuine utility. If I have indeed identified Azzouni's core point (which is sound), it seems like a lot of pages to say something fairly simple. I do agree with it.

Comment: (If that procedure works when stranded on an island, or for a mathematician alone in his study, it can also work for someone introspecting, concerned with the contents of their mind. Provided they do have those two things, and humans do have them. They are the two main components of intelligence.)

Comment: PLA shows that there has to be a check on referring languages, and Wittgenstein surmises that social practice typically serves as such a check. Azzouni suggests that reality itself can provide the check, but in a limited way and under many restrictions. Wittgenstein's examples with naming qualia do not clear them, for instance. We need (at least) "cooperative environment", responsive dispositions and practically consequential referents. I also suspect that Azzouni's languages, while loosely meaningful, are not, strictly speaking, referring in Wittgenstein's sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148366/discussion-between-causative-and-conifold).

Comment: @Conifold In the document you linked, Azzouni doesn't mention cooperative environments, responsive dispositions, or practically consequential referents. So this is your own theory, right? (posting here as well as in chat because of your previously stated preference)

Comment: He does, just in more words, I do not have a theory. Compressing for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid you won’t find this project very satisfying. The PLA is not a doctrine or a set of beliefs. Many people have tried to reformulate it in that way, with mixed success. But it is more than a theory or doctrine; it is a re-interpretation of our language and thinking about pain and, by extension, other experiences. The benefit is that we can escape from various philosophical quagmires.

Perhaps a comparison will help. You may know the story of Dr. Johnson’s “refutation” of Berkeley’s arguments for immaterialism. In case you don’t, Boswell tells it as follows:-

> After we came out of the church, we stood talking for some time together of Bishop Berkeley's ingenious sophistry to prove the non-existence of matter, and that every thing in the universe is merely ideal. I observed, that though we are satisfied his doctrine is untrue, it is impossible to refute it. I shall never forget the alacrity with which Johnson answered, striking his foot with mighty force against a large stone, till he rebounded from it,– "I refute it thus."

See [George Berkeley - Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Berkeley)

The odd thing about this is that although Dr. Johnson thought that Berkeley was denying plain common sense, Berkeley is at great pains (both in the *Treatise* and in the *Dialogues*) to insist that he is not contradicting common sense; his aim is just to correct a mistaken philosophical theory. In the same way, Wittgenstein’s argument does not try to contradict ordinary non-philosophical life or language, but to re-orient philosophy so that it no longer wanders through a maze of puzzlement generated by a misleading model of introspection.

You’re asking a lot in your list of propositions. In this context, very few of them have straightforward answers. A proper answer to them would disentangle the philosophical models from the everyday use of language, but that would inflate this answer to inordinate length and I’m concerned that it would become a TL;DR or lead to a long and confusing discussion.

At the heart of it is the conventional philosophical doctrine about introspection. This observes that if I say I am afraid or feeling pain or thinking of a beetle, no-one else can meaningfully contradict me. This is what “privacy” means in this context, and it is quite different from the caterpillars and beetles that children used to keep in match-boxes or from some secret vice indulged in only when on one’s own (“in privacy”). Those privacies can be violated. But it is not logically possible to violate this kind of privacy.

So introspective knowledge becomes a gold standard, alongside logic, of what knowledge (certainty) is. The catch is that, just because it cannot be wrong, it isn’t really meaningful to speak of it being right. (The same point led to logical truths being classified as “trivial”).

The argument is that this model of introspection needs to be replaced, and his idea is that “I am in pain” should not be compared to “The patient is in pain”, but to “Ouch!”. It is an expression of pain, not an observation about it, and belongs alongside wincing, clutching the affected part &c. Consequently it is not true or false in the way that ordinary observations are.

The crucial point here is that the symptoms of pain are part of the concept of pain and not an add-on – and, incidentally, so is the impulse to help on the part of other people. (He doesn’t comment on sadism.)

Of course, there is more to be said here. For a start, “I am in pain” is not simply a variant of “Ouch”, but plays a part in the public language game. However, there is no point in my trying to duplicate the various expositions of the argument, which I’m sure you are quite capable of looking up on your own. But perhaps identifying the starting-point of the argument and its terminus will be helpful.

**In response to your request, here is my response to each of your questions.**

1. People have private mental lives. *Yes, but they can be revealed and/or shared.*
2. People have subjective experiences. *People do experience things. Experiences are subjective by definition.*
3. Pain is real. *Fake pain and mimicked pain are not real. Phantom pains, psychosomatic pains and referred pains are real. Normally, physical injuries are really painful.*
4. People have P-consciousness. *I’m not familiar with this concept; I must be out of date. No comment.*
5. People have qualia. *Another concept that I’m not very familiar with. No comment.*
6. A person may go off alone and think by himself. *Yes.*
7. Language is used to transmit concepts from one person's mind to another. That is: there was a private concept in one person's mind, then a public utterance, and then a similar private concept appeared in a second person's mind. *I accept that one of the functions of language is communication between people. But the question assumes a model of language that I find very problematic.*
8. A person, alone, may use language to conjure images in his own mind. Assuming he does not have aphantasia. (If you are a PLA believer, do you have aphantasia?) *Certainly people imagine things and “using language” (using language to do what?) may be a helpful stimulus.*
9. There is an objective reality, independent of what people say about it. *Whether my car is still parked where I left it does not depend on what I want or believe or suspect.*
10. A social consensus, even a unanimous one, can be incorrect. *Yes, and another social consensus (such as driving on the left or right hand side of the road) can be neither correct nor incorrect.*
11. People often have an internal dialogue. *I would have said yes. However, the model that you link to is not wrong, but is extremely problematic.*
12. A person may decide that the word "lurrim" (for example) will be his private synonym for "table," tell this to no one else, and use this word in a meaningful way in his internal dialogue. *This is just a variant of question 13. The question is what “meaningful” means.*
13. If a person has a literal, physical, beetle in a box (as Wittgenstein famously discussed as a metaphor), shown to no-one else, then statements the person makes about the literal beetle are still meaningful and may be true or false depending on how well they match the physical characteristics of the beetle. *This is just a variant of question 12. The question is what “meaningful” means.*
14. A person may hear what others say, but then he must decide for himself whether he will believe it, based on his own sense of reason. Ultimately, this personal sense of reason is the "gatekeeper" of what beliefs go into a person's mind. *Certainly, nobody else can make up my mind for me. But I don’t know what you mean by “a personal sense of reason”. I suspect that a philosophical thesis that I might disagree with is buried in it.*
15. Psychology is a legitimate field of study. *Sometimes it is. But it depends on what you mean by “psychology” and “legitimate”. In this respect, it is no different from physics or etmylogy.*
16. Language is primarily a social activity. *Surely that’s a cliché. Certainly, it’s not unique to PLA believers.*
17. It can be difficult, often impossible, for a person to accurately share his private mental experiences with others. *Yes. But how is it decided when a person has accurately shared his private mental experiences?*
18. As a practical matter, because of the difficulty of sharing private mental experiences, we should avoid speaking about them in a philosophical context. The potential for confusion and talking past each other is too high. *That seems like an unwise and unrealistic policy to me. The difficulties can be overcome.*
19. It is better to "think with other people," trying to build consensus and adopting existing consensus, than to ruminate or meditate by oneself. *Both solitary and social thinking are to be recommended.*

Comment: This is a thoughtful answer. The sticking point for me is when you say it isn't really meaningful to speak of, "I am feeling pain," as being right. It might not be possible for *other* people to verify that it is right, but truth or falsehood of a statement does not depend on what people think about it (that's why I included statement 10). Certainly, if I say right now, "I am feeling pain in my left big toe," I am wrong, and lying; statements about pain can be introspectively wrong. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: One last question. Do *you* think the PLA makes sense, and if you do, which of the 19 statements would you affirm? Even if you don't consider your views on these statements to be "part" of the PLA, I am interested in what views "go along incidentally" with belief in the PLA. For instance, you have said that it's not meaningful to speak of statements about pain being right. Does this mean you don't think pain is real, or not? Or you just "remain silent" on the question of whether pain is real?

Comment: About PLA I've little opinion/comment. About introspection: Yes the fact I'm hopelessly locked in my head, you in yours etc and we cannot directly know the insides of others is true.... 99.99% of the time. When you've experienced real telepathy you know it's not 100%. And the gap between 99.99% and 100% makes one realize this argument is contingent, pragmatic. But not *a priori* /analytic.

Comment: @causative. I agree that what I said about introspection was over-simplified; I registered that in my last paragraph. I agree that if you reject the traditional view of introspection, then the private language argument has no target. So there are issues about the argument. However, I think they are a complication, not a refutation of the argument.

Comment: @causative. OK. I'll comment on your questions. But I've noticed that insistence on  yes or no to questions is most often deployed by interviewers and lawyers who want to trap someone into an answer that damages them. From my perspective, it feels very aggressive. So I'll answer in my own way, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Rushi Well, I accept that you experience your life in that way. How could I contradict you? However, I'm sorry for you. Your situation reveals one of the great weaknesses of the idea that our experience is independent of what we believe and illustrates why I don't believe in qualia. No doubt my view reflects the fact that I have not experienced telepathy and doubt if I would accept any experience as telepathic. So no discussion is possible and we must agree to disagree. That's a pity. Could I ask why you bother with philosophy?

Comment: @LudwigV Evidently something in my comment evoked a strong trigger — apologies!
If I know what it was I can try to address it, but I really cant make out what caused so much upset. [Just to be clear Ive no telepathic power but Ive seen persons that could read others as effortlessly as you read this site; and other 'lesser miracles' like telling distant details about patient's life by reading the pulse]
Also if there is some real question I will address it. Just that *Why do you bother with philosophy?* juxtaposed with *Im sorry for you* seems like a rhetorical more than a genuine question.

Comment: @LudwigV Refusing to answer questions about your position is a poor attitude in a philosophical discussion, if you ask me. If you believe in the soundness of your position, then you have nothing to lose by exposing it in all its glory. If you believe it is *not* sound and weaknesses would be made clear through questioning, then you are dishonestly hiding those weaknesses. Or perhaps you think your answers would be misinterpreted - you don't trust me not to form strawmen of them. Well, I won't do so deliberately, or if I do so accidentally you can correct me.

Comment: Often I do ask questions with the intent of showing a weakness in someone's position - that's the Socratic method, elenchus, a good thing! When doing elenchus I would never deliberately misinterpret the answers. However, at the moment I am not trying elenchus. I'm literally just trying to find out what positions tend to go along with PLA. If you just say something like "1-5 are meaningless, assent to 6-12, 14, 17, dissent to the others" I'm not looking for anything more. Philosophers should be forthright and direct.

Comment: @Rushi There was indeed a trigger in my response to you. Your remark "Yes the fact I'm hopelessly locked in my head, you in yours" seemed to close the issue I though I was discussing in a dogmatic way. If I seemed short-tempered, I apologize and offer the extremely hot weather here by way of excuse. You see, I don't see myself as locked in my head, but as resident in it - and not unhappy there. What would it be to escape my head (in the sense of "head" that's relevant here)?

Comment: @causative I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I wasn't (as you now see) refusing to answer questions, just protesting at being expected to answer them in a specific way. Perhaps my response shows why? However, it may be that I was a bit paranoid. Your response is very reassuring, so I apologize for the paranoia and will try to produce a brief response along the lines you indicate.

Comment: Whew! Good to know. Ok *X (you,me,generic-one) locked in the head* is strong. Especially for myself who rejects cartesian mind-body dualism in favor of Merleau-Ponty-Lakhoff's embodied cognition. But still if you summarily reject qualia which are generally regarded as [fundamental open philosophy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_philosophical_problems) then you can hardly complain about the consequences of rejecting qualia aka *What would it be to escape my head?* The problem of Qualia is precisely that we are solitary prisoners in 'our head' (metaphorical if you prefer)

Comment: So my answers are 1 – 3 Yes; 6 – 15 Yes. 4,5 Skip and 16, 17 Yes; 18 No; 19 Both. Sorry to still be awkward. I can't help it.

Comment: *What would it be to escape my head?* For a strikingly direct answer See [Harding](https://www.headless.org/on-having-no-head.htm)

Comment: Oh, if that's what you meant, it's a whole different kettle of fish! I think I may download the ebook - it's free and I like a bargain. But I would still recommend that he wear a hard hat on building sites and bicycles. I don't know how to discuss this in this context. Sorry.

Comment: @Rushi Embodied Cognition - or even Embodied Psychology seems to me an excellent idea. My problem with qualia is clearly stated in the first sentence of the Wikipedia entry you gave me. "The question hinges on whether color is a product of the mind or an inherent property of objects." I think that's a false dilemma. I can't explain in the confines of a comment, and I'm not sure if it makes sense. But it starts with the observation that both sides are necessary for the phenomenon to occur. So I want to say the colour is in the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood Wittgenstein’s argument. The argument is not that one can’t create a language in their head and find meaning in certain terms. Neither is it that one can’t create a language that others would have a hard time deciphering as a practical matter.

The argument is that one can’t create a private language that others, even **in principle**, can’t decipher. The reason this is such is simply because if it was **in principle** unintelligible by others, it would be unintelligible by the proponent of the language as well. But then it wouldn’t be a private language.

The consequence of this is that it might not make any sense to talk of private experiences or of private mental states.

Comment: So, which of the 19 statements would you say a PLA believer would assent to? The kinds of languages "allowed" under the PLA, even if we take the words you just said as a good interpretation, heavily depends on what you consider "in principle" decipherable. For example, is a language about one's private qualia "in principle" decipherable?

Comment: As per the article, “ What Wittgenstein had in mind is a language conceived as necessarily comprehensible only to its single originator because the things which define its vocabulary are necessarily inaccessible to others.”

Comment: The consequence of this is that it might not make any sense to talk of private experiences or of private mental states.

Comment: That would be why I included statements 1-5. Also, Wittgenstein's "beetle" scenario does not involve language that is *in principle* unshareable, only language that in practice is not shared because people don't look at each other's beetles. It seems he was more concerned with what he thought happened in practice when people used language, than what might be in principle possible.

Comment: Well a language wouldn’t be needed if referring to only private items is the gist of his point from what I can gather. Language must refer to public items. If it refers to things only you have seen then you wouldn’t need a word for it: you would just know it.

Comment: I hate to be dogmatic and I will have to look again at what he said. But my belief is that Wittgenstein was not talking about a beetle that could be shown to anyone else, but to a beetle that was inaccessible to anyone else. A bit like an invisible friend, only in a box. Whatever I say about my invisible friend is, if you insist, true, but vacuously true.

Answer (score 1):

I read the PLA in three tiers, and the first two are articulated in the Stanford link in your question.

Wittgenstein was inclined strongly toward both behaviorism and logical positivism, and the overt argument he presented is a behaviorist attack on the ability of any verification of a private experience or thought.  This is the “orthodox” interpretation of the PLA.  Critics of this argument are conceded to be correct in the SEP article.  Public language also has no foolproof error correction method, as we see with linguistic drift and dynamism, so this cannot be a valid criticism of private language.  The only thing actually lacking in private thought is 3rd person confirmation, and with the collapse of both the verification principle and the entire failed behaviorist dogma, this is no longer the central concern that W considered it to be.

W’s overt argument is also in conflict with our own experience of observing say a sunset, enjoying it, but then struggling to translate our thoughts into public language to share.

Also, a peculiar outcome of the orthodox argument is that there absurdly can be no last speaker of a dying language. Nor a first speaker of a new one.  Only a second to last speaker, or second speaker!

So, moving on to the second tier of interpretation.  Your question 9 is on target. The basic reasoning here, and what Conifold I think is getting at, is that our thoughts appear to be too indefinite to be able to say there even IS a “fact if the matter” about them. The recursion of evaluating what we think we think is just too squirrelly to be nailed down to be “the reality of the world” that one can even do a truth test evaluation against.

I believe the point of tier 2 of this argument is to question whether your point 1 is possibly compatible with point 9. Do tier 2 PLA advocates dispute point 1?  I think they do not dispute its SEEMING to be the case, but then dispute that we can use any such seeming to draw conclusions from.

Tier 3 you touch upon with 10. None of us are omniscient.  There IS no “ view from nowhere”.  3rd person perspective is as subject to undiscoverable error in principle as first person perspectives.  If first person thoughts are too squirrelly to treat as possible facts then so are 3rd person shared thoughts.  The post structuralists noted this about all expressed thought — there are embedded assumptions in all language and social structures that skew what we take “reality” to be, that we cannot justify and in general can rarely even identify if we try.  The tier 3 extension of the tier 2 argument takes Kripke’s reasoning to its logical absurdity of rejecting all knowledge.

I believe that Dennett’s Multiple Drafts model points to a useful alternative POV than that pursued by analytic philosophy. IF our thoughts do not have a singular definable state, but are a dynamic collection of related and changing content, then our private thoughts, and private language, can exist and have meaning even if there may not be explicit facts about them per point 9.

This is to accept pragmatic rather than absolute truth.  That our external observations and community thinking may also be in error would then be no more of an obstacle to having knowledge than the dynamism of our thoughts is to their existing. And while both first person and 3rd person checks are fallible, 3rd person are LESS fallible, hence do give us a more useful/ reliable approximation to “reality”.

Answer (score 0):

First off, *confetior*, I haven't read Ludwig Wittgenstein. All I have to go on is discussions on internet fora. It seems he's quite a star northwest of the English channel.

Anyway, the private language argument (PLA, affectionately) has *cryptographical* undertones. Say person X invents a private language which they and only they understand. That qualifies, *sensu amplissimo*, as a *coded message*. It needs a *key* for *decipherment*. The key is *not* public per the definition of a private language. Think Rosetta Stone (the key that unlocked Egyptian). What this means is, for all intents and purposes, the *coded message* is indistinguishable from *gibberish/gobbledygook*. Hence, a private languge is *unintelligible* to anyone but the person who invents the private language (X). The sticking point then is, is a private language *intelligible* to its inventor? To my reckoning, this is a question in *cryptography*. What kinda misfortune may befall a key, if it exists at all? Lost? Corrupted?

The *rongorongo script* (consisting of pictograms on wooden blocks) remains undeciphered till date. Is it a *private language*?

Adieu ...

Comment: The _rongorongo_ script is an undeciphered script, which means it is not private in the sense relevant to the PLA. A private language in the PLA means a language which can only be decrypted by the key-holder, so that effectively an encrypted message means whatever the key holder decides. For philosophical purposes, a key that can be or even could have been shared is enough to qualify the encrypted language as a public language. The Rosetta stone, like Linear B script and the Enigma Code were only deciphered because a guess struck lucky. Wikipedia has entries for all three. Good stories all.

Comment: But perhaps the philosophically relevant part of the stories is how they proved that their decoding was correct. That's also part of the record. The process was different in each case. There's no royal road.